# Window Navigation in Catel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I am working on a WPF Application with Catel that has a Login Screen. How would I, after a user has entered his details and may proceed) close the Login Screen and display a 'Home' Screen using Catel?

I tried using the IUIVisualizerService, but I cannot pass it the user's name, for example, to be used within the viewmodel of the view that sits on the window to be opened, unless I am doing it wrong.

I have other scenarios in my application where I would need to open a new window from a currently opened one(I may require to close it before the new one is opened) and pass some data to the contained view's viewmodel.

Any suggestions?

**SOME CODE AS REQUESTED:**

```
/// <summary>
    /// ViewModel for the Login Screen
    /// </summary>
    public class LoginWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public LoginWindowViewModel()
        {
            ShowHomeWindow = new Command(OnShowHomeWindowExecute);
        }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public override string Title { get { return "Login"; } }

        public Command ShowHomeWindow { get; private set; }

        private void OnShowHomeWindowExecute()
        {
            var viewModel = new HomeWindowViewModel();

            var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
            var uiVisualizerService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUIVisualizerService>();
            uiVisualizerService.Register(typeof(HomeWindowViewModel), typeof(HomeWindow));
            uiVisualizerService.Show(viewModel, OnWindowClosed);
        }

        private void OnWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ViewModel for the Home Window
    /// </summary>
    public class HomeWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public HomeWindowViewModel()
        {
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ViewModel for the Home View that sits in Home Window
    /// </summary>
    public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public HomeViewModel()
        {

        }

        public string Username { get; set; }

    }
```

So what needs to happen is that the Username from the LoginView's ViewModel (which is a UserControl on the LoginWindow) must get passed along to the Username on the HomeView's ViewModel (which is also a UserControl and sits on the HomeWindow).

This code is not important as this is a made up scenario. The core of what I am trying to figure out is how one would pass info along to other Windows' View's ViewModel when it is generated elsewhere.

Comment: show some code, eg how you initialize the VM, how you navigate to the home screen etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [getting started with WPF](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Getting+started+with+WPF) part of the docs. Normally there are services that manage selections / contain application-wide states. Then you let them be injected into your view models whenever you need them.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I was looking for.